# In ES6/React How do I reference the key of a nested object in a list contex?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Presently, I have a class with state and render() as such:

```
class ExchangeContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      exchanges:[
        {
          name:"binance",
          url:"https://binance.com"
        },
        {
          name:"bittrex",
          url:"https://bittrex.com"
        }
      ]
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="ExchangeContainer list-group">
        <ExchangeList exchanges={this.state.exchanges}/>
        <ExchangeDetail />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Notice the state is passed as a React prop. That prop is then used (below) in a different object:

```
  getListItem = (exchangeUrl, exchangeName) => (
    <a className="nav-link active" href={exchangeUrl}>
      {exchangeName}
    </a>
  );

  render() {
    return (
      <li className="list-group-item">
        {this.getListItem(this.props.exchange.url, this.props.exchange.name)}
      </li>
    );
  }
```

Given the above, assuming I modify the state object to be an object instead of an array as such:

```
this.state = {
      exchanges:{
        binance:{
          url:"https://binance.com"
        },
        bittrex:{
          url:"https://bittrex.com"
        }
      }
    };
```

How do I modify the ES6 bit later on to reference the key of the object (I'm thinking of treating this like an associative array in perl if that helps - e.g. "binance") instead of looking for this.props.exchanges.name, which no longer exists? For example (psuedocode - look at second argument is now "key" instead of "name")

```
  render() {
    return (
      <li className="list-group-item">
        {this.getListItem(this.props.exchange.url, this.props.exchange.key)} //KEY not NAME
      </li>
    );
```

Comment: what is `an associate array` or `associative array`? no such animal exists in the world of javascript - do you mean "object" ?

Comment: Yes, I think "object" is more appropriate. I've modified my question to better reflect conventional js lingo. Thank you.

Comment: so, in effect, you want to convert `[
        {
          name:"binance",
          url:"https://binance.com"
        },
        {
          name:"bittrex",
          url:"https://bittrex.com"
        }
      ]` to `{
        binance:{
          url:"https://binance.com"
        },
        bittrex:{
          url:"https://bittrex.com"
        }
      }` ? ... `this.state.exchanges.reduce((r, {name, url}) => (r[name] = {url}, r), {})`

Comment: Yes, and then the difficult bit seems to be how to make the ES6 magic that it just knows to treat "exchange" like a list, how to make it do about the same thing that I can reference the key (is that still a correct term with respect to the object?) as I might reference the index of the current array (if that's even possible - something like this.props.exchange.curIndex)

I could just pass in the entire new exchange object like: 

`getListItem(this.props.exchange)`

And then let the getListItem method sort it out using exchange.keys but I guess I am asking for the cleanest ES6 solution.

Comment: `Object.entries(this.state.exchanges)` results in `[["binance", {url: ...}],["bittres", {url:...}]]` ... does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Your new `state.exchange` is one object with many keys. 
You can convert it back to the original array format, like so:

```
const state = {
    exchanges:{
        binance:{
            url:"https://binance.com"
        },
        bittrex:{
            url:"https://bittrex.com"
        }
    }
};

// Convert from object format to array
const stateAsArray = Object.keys(state.exchanges).map(key => {
    const ex = state.exchanges[key];
    // add key
    ex.name = key;
    return ex;
})

console.log(stateAsArray);
// => [ { url: 'https://binance.com', name: 'binance' },
//      { url: 'https://bittrex.com', name: 'bittrex' } ]
```

Now you have an array. You can use it as you were using it before.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *for ... in* statement though the order of iteration of the keys will be arbitrary. Also, browser compatibility should not be an issue.

Please visit the link for detailed information - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Answer (score 0):

In part because of how some other code (not mentioned in the question), it turns out what I had was about the best I can get and really my question doesn't make sense. I can't really do anything like I was guessing might be possible.